# Как исправить Permission denied shell?

Tags: android, linux, shell

```
if /data/data/com.android.chrome/app_tabs/0/tab_state0 | grep -q "sait.ru"; then
  echo "true"
else
 echo "false"
fi
```

Получаю ошибку Permission denied. Объясните в чем дело. Читал в сторону Chmod но к результату не привело. Апарат андройд + su + busybox. Права терминалу предоставлены.

Comment: вы пытаетесь «выполнить» файл `/data/data/com.android.chrome/app_tabs/0/tab_state0`

Comment: совершенно не понял вашего комментария. ещё раз повторю: вы **зачем-то** пытаетесь **выполнить** явно **не**-исполнимый файл. потому и получаете озвученную ошибку.

Comment: Должно быть `grep -q "..." /path/to/file`.

Answer (score 2):

Вы пытаетесь выполнить не исполняемый файл (*regular file*), а не передать его содержимое в `grep`.

Moжно так:

```
if grep -q "sait.ru" /data/data/com.android.chrome/app_tabs/0/tab_state0; then ...
```

Или так:

```
if < /data/data/com.android.chrome/app_tabs/0/tab_state0 grep -q "sait.ru"; then ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы выполняли команду su в терминале? Permission denied - значит отказано в доступе по причине недостатка привилегий. Нужно работать от root или правильно выставить chmod, работайте от root и выполняйте chmod 7777 /исполняемый/файл и не партесь.

Comment: Вы уверены, что ваш ответ поможет в решении?

Comment: @0xdb, у автора 2 ошибки. Первая - синтаксис. Вторая - отсутствие прав. Нельзя в андроиде без рута даже просто смотреть содержимое папки `/data`. Необходимо работать от рута.

Comment: @Flippy В вопросе - "+ su + busybox. Права терминалу предоставлены" - думаю, что работа под root, т. ч. 2-я ошибка маловероятна.